# What is the best way to mock object instantiated inside method under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the following code and I look for the best way to test it:

```
public class ClientFactory {

    private ConfigurationLoader loader;

    public ClientFactory(ConfigurationLoader loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }


  public IRest create(String something) {
    Configuration config = loader.load(something);

    if (magic()) {
        return new ClientType1(config); 
    }    

    return new ClientType2(config); 
  }

}  

public class ClientType1 implements IRest{

  private Configuration config;

  public ClientType1(Configuration config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public Something doGetRequest(Long id) {
    WebClient client = getHttpClient();

    return client.get();        
  }

  private WebClient getHttpClient() {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.setSchema(config.getSchema());
    client.setHostname(config.getHostname());
    client.setPort(config.getPort());

    // and so on ....

    return client;

  }

}
```

I would like to test the interaction/behaviour between ConfigurationLoader and ClientType1.getHttpClient methods. From one side I think it is good idea, testing interaction between objects, from the other side, hmmm I test setters and getters - boring, no business logig is involved here. Which one is more true?

Mock of configuration object can be easily transferred into ClientType1 when it is instantiated, mocking the  'new WebClient()' seems to be the problem. I thought about:

```
public class ClientType1 implements IRest{

  private Configuration config;
  private WebClient client; // this will be replaced by mock

  public ClientType1(Configuration config) {
    this.config = config;
    webClient =  new WebClient();
  }

  .....

  private Client getHttpClient() {       
    client.setSchema(config.getSchema());
    ....

    return client;    
  }
}
```

and use PowerMock to replace `private WebClient client` by mock, but I am not sure it is **java way**. Any guidelines/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, the `new` keyword makes unit testing difficult. I suggest avoiding it. I think your problem here is more of a design problem. Objects should *not* configure themselves. When you design an object, think about what its true dependencies are. IMO the true dependency of the `ClientType1` is a `WebClient` or a pool of `WebClient` not a `Configuration`. IMO the true dependency of `ClientFactory` is a `Configuration` not a `String`.

I would redesign like so:

```
interface ClientFactory {
    IRest create(Configuration config);
}

public class DefaultClientFactory implements ClientFactory {
    private final ClientFactory magicClientFactory;
    private final ClientFactory otherClientFactory;

    public DefaultClientFactory(ClientFactory magicClientFactory, ClientFactory otherClientFactory) {
        this.magicClientFactory = magicClientFactory;
        this.otherClientFactory = otherClientFactory;
    }

    public IRest create(Configuration config) {
        if (magic()) {
            return magicClientFactory.create(config);
        } else {
            return otherClientFactory.create(config);
        }
    }
}

interface WebClientFactory {
    WebClient create(Configuration config);
}

public class DefaultWebClientFactory implements WebClientFactory {
    public WebClient create(Configuration config) {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.setSchema(config.getSchema());
        client.setHostname(config.getHostname());
        client.setPort(config.getPort());
        return client;
    }
}

public class ClientType1Factory implements ClientFactory {
    private final WebClientFactory webClientFactory;

    public ClientType1Factory(WebClientFactory webClientFactory) {
        this.webClientFactory = webClientFactory;
    }

    public IRest create(Configuration config) {
        return new ClientType1(webClientFactory.create(config));
    }
}

public class ClientType1 implements IRest{

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public ClientType1(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Something doGetRequest(Long id) {
        return webClient.get();        
    }
}
```

Using this design you can successfully unit test each and every class defined without resorting to advanced features of PowerMock. You can unit test `ClientType1` by passing in a mock `WebClient`. You can also test your factories by passing in different configurations and checking if the created object is what you expect. Further the code is less coupled, more flexible, and each class has a single responsibility.